# Trouble in invoking a method from one java class to another

Tags: java

I have a folder **PackagesAndMethods** . Within that folder I had two files

1. TestMethods.java
2. MyMethods.java

The code within those files are,

***TestMethod.java***

```
package PackagesAndMethods;

public class TestMethods
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {       
        int result = MyMethods.Total();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

***MyMethods.java***

```
package PackagesAndMethods;

public class MyMethods
{
    public static int Total()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

The problem is the "MyMethods.java" class compiles successfully but when compiling the "TestMethods.java", i am getting the bellow error

```
error: cannot find symbol
                int result = MyMethods.Total();
                             ^
  symbol:   variable MyMethods
  location: class TestMethods
1 error
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hou do you compile your class? Is the compiled class MyMethods in classpath?

Comment: Please tell us more about how you're compiling everything. Also note that both the package name and the method name should be lowercase to follow Java naming conventions. That probably won't be the problem, but it helps to get into good habits.

Comment: Also, if you're using an IDE (You should), try "Clean" and then retry - sometimes the IDE is out of synch and cleaning and rebuilding makes sure you have the latest version compiled.

Comment: @Jens : I am compiling the class files with cmd prompt using the commands `D:\Java\PackagesAndMethods>javac MyMethods.java` and 
`D:\Java\PackagesAndMethods>javac TestMethods.java` . The first one compiled successfully and got the class file in "PackagesAndMethods" folder. But having that error in compiling second one - "TestMethods.java".

Comment: @amit : Yes I tried cleaning the folder and compiled the classes again but nothing changed.

Comment: @JonSkeet : Please find the above comments for how am compiling and yes, sure i will follow the Java naming conventions here after. Now am new to java environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you're compiling. You should generally be compiling from the "package root", ideally specifying an output root as well. For example, from the parent directory (`D:\Java`):

```
> javac -d classes PackagesAndMethods\MyMethods.java
> javac -d classes -cp classes PackagesAndMethods\TestMethods.java
```

Or more simply:

```
> javac -d classes PackagesAndMethods\*.java
```

Currently the compiler is expecting to find a directory called `PackagesAndMethods` to look in for classes in the `PackagesAndMethods` directory.

I'd personally separate the source into its own separate directory to keep it well away from the output, so you end up with:

```
> javac -d classes src\PackagesAndMethods\*.java
```

You're likely to find it simpler to start with if you work in an IDE which manages all of this for you though. It's still worth separating out the source and output.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to compile MyMethods.java first. then Compile TestMethod.java. then run TestMethod.

I think you are compiling TestMethod.java first. so compiler not able to find MyMethods.class file.

Comment: No I have compiled the "MyMethods.java" and got the class file inside the **PackagesAndMethods** folder. But the "TestMethods.java" is not compiling. That is the problem..

Comment: first create a directory with the name PackagesAndMethods. place all .java files in that..                                       compile MyMethods.java and place in PackagesAndMethods folder. dhen change your current working directory to the parent directory. Ex if path is c:\PackagesAndMethods     Change to C:\ then execute C:\>javac -cp .  PackagesAndMethods/TestMethods.java

Answer (score 0):

If I compile with this command:

javac.exe PackagesAndMethods*.java

the files is compiled without any errors

Comment: I my case i got the error `javac: file not found: PackagesAndMethods*.java` when compiling with the command `javac.exe PackagesAndMethods*.java`

Comment: excuse me javac.exe PackagesAndMethods\\*.java

Answer (score -1):

variable MyMethods is not declared, you should create an instance of class MyMethods as `MyMethods myMethods = new MyMethods();` and use `myMethods.Total();`
(remember, instances should be lower case, classes uppercase, methods lowercase

Comment: It is a "static" method, so should be callable directly.